# Android Studio got extremely slow

Tags: flutter, android-studio

At least for Flutter, not sure about other SDKs.

Please see what I mean here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rowb.jpg

Auto complete, Alt+Enter on a Widget, indentation, etc all take so long now, I'm not sure what happened.

Is there any way I can fix this? I updated everything but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: It depends on your device config I believe, you can try vs-code which is lighter.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am running this on a R5 3600X and an RTX 3080, it's a gaming PC. I don't think my device is the issue, RAM is also 32GB.

Comment: Yap, your device is more than enough

Comment: how many `dart` processes do you see on the task manager? in normal case it should be 3-4 but sometimes they are not killed by a previous session

Comment: @pskink I saw only 2. I tried the Invalidate Cache and Restart option but still the same issue.

Comment: so it seems there are other processes slowing down your pc - i have only 4GB on my Linux box but still with vscode,  autocomplete works like a light speed ;-)

Comment: @pskink Yeah thanks, it's time I ditched AS for good for VSCode.